# Net::HTTPBadGateway when trying to fetch some JSON

Tags: ruby, http

Im working in a small sinatra app that i want it to fetch a json file for latter use.
Using browser, i can access the json just OK, also on irb:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'open-uri'
 => true 
1.9.2p320 :002 > metrics = open "http://foo-bar.com:8085/metrics/index.json"
 => #<File:/tmp/open-uri20130529-12715-1upc3bm> 
1.9.2p320 :003 > metrics.read
 => "[\"carbon.agents.io-a.avgUpdateTime\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.cache.overflow\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.cache.queries\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.cache.queues\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.cache.size\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.committedPoints\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.cpuUsage\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.creates\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.errors\", \"carbon.agents.io-a.memUsage\" ...
```

it returns me the desired file.

But when i try to do the same from sinatra_app.rb:

```
get '/json' do
  @all_metrics = open @graphite_all_metrics
  erb :json
end
```

or

```
get '/json' do
  @all_metrics = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI @graphite_all_metrics)
  erb :json
end
```

returns me a 502 bad gateway error.
Any help?

How i get @graphite_all_metrics:

```
@graphite_base = "http://foo-bar.com:8085/"
@graphite_all_metrics = [@graphite_base, "/metrics/index.json"].join
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a misconfigured multi-domain dns. Nothing with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your `join`

```
@graphite_all_metrics = [@graphite_base, "/metrics/index.json"].join
```

is adding a double slash to the URL. Use

```
@graphite_all_metrics = File.join(@graphite_base, "/metrics/index.json")
```

or just remove one of the slashes from your example.

Most browsers/programs will fix double slash errors, but there could be some issue with your server setup.

Comment: puts @graphite_all_metrics, and it is OK, no doubled slashes.
http://foo.bar:8085/metrics/index.json
 Also hardcoding the URI gives me the same 502